# Почему уменьшается качество 2d картинки при уменьшении?

Tags: unity3d

Возникла проблема, картинка на общем плане по качеству выглядит хуже, чем есть на самом деле и это бросается в глаза, можно ли это как-то подправить, не увеличивая размер объекта на сцене? Пробовал создавать картинку большего размера, но ничего не изменялось.

[image: Картина на сцене]

[image: При запуске игры]

[image: На общем плане]

Comment: Когда растягиваешь картинку слишком маленького качества она выглядит плохо, почти всем очевидно почему. Но как не странно, сильное уменьшение картинки большого качества это другая крайность. Причины как-бы другие, но по сути те-же, если в первом случае информации о изображении слишком мало, то в втором слишком много. На расточительную дополнительную обработку изображений находящихся в зоне безумных крайностей ресурсы разумеется не тратятся, это не редактор растровой графики.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, как я понимаю, решить эту проблему нельзя? Или уменьшение качества картинки может спасти в данной ситуации? Ведь информации о изображении не будет слишком много и по сути качество не должно будет сильно ухудшаться.